# xcode error after updating cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I updated `cocoapods` from version `1.2.1` to `1.5.3`

After updating i cant run my project on any device/simulator.

Getting an error:

[image: error]

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: did you try `pod install` the project and reopen again?

Comment: Yep, pod install/update/reopen xcode/restart macbook

Comment: Restarting my Macbook for the second time worked for me.

Comment: Restarting my Macbook for the second time worked for me.

Comment: nice! good to know

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project and restart xCode and system will work.